# Email Notification if the IMPORTED DATA in sheet changes. [Triggers not working]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I do not know GAS and I tried searching a lot of codes and found one very close.

I wish to receive email notification when the data in the current sheet changes. *Right now when I make changes, I get an email. Which is fine **but I will not make changes to the sheet actually because the data is being imported from another sheet/website***

**Basically I wish to**

1. **receive a notification when there is a change in Imported data. No one will ever edit this.**
2. **Attach a Permanent Excel sheet with email**
3. **in the end of email, total number of rows affected = +-4**

Dummy Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BTdA7Rx16W6la_gri4uP079yIzzgKfZKO610yfQ6724/edit?usp=sharing [Triggers Not Working on Imported Data]

Current Script:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var to = "ashwendra10625@gmail.com";
  var message = '\n\nSignature';
  if(cell.indexOf('G')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Data Updated';
  var body = 'Hi there,\n\nThe data on website was updated recently.\n\nKindly refresh the previous excel sheet or click ' + 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BTdA7Rx16W6la_gri4uP079yIzzgKfZKO610yfQ6724/edit#gid=0' + ' to see changes.\n\n\nThe changes are:\nTotal Rows affected: ' + row + '\n' + message;
  MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body);
};
```

Comment: I think onEdit() only happens when a user makes the change.  I would consider using a sidebar and javascript setTimeout() function to poll that value every few seconds and keep track of past values in the PropertiesService, or a separate file or perhaps even a database with JDBC.

Comment: @cooper can we use =counta() in the sheet and send a notification when the number changes. But im not sure how will I make this program. I dont know Gas actually

Comment: Well you'd still have to use trigger to initiate the send and most of the simple triggers require some user action to take place.  Check the documentation.  Read the [Getting Started Section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). If you getting changes from a Form Submission then you could use the onFormSubmit event.

Comment: @Cooper is correct, `onChange()`/`onEdit()` is triggered by a user making an edit/change (tested it). Any edit/change made by a script will not be detected by this simple or installable triggers. And AFAIK, there is no method available to count the affected/updated cells. You may want to follow Cooper's idea regarding the affected cells. You can also check the [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) for workaround. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cooper's is good but its not working. Also in case when data will have a decrese in rows, it wont notify

Comment: How does the data change during an import? Are we talking about the sheet named Dashboard?

Comment: @Cooper I'll be fetching data from a website. Th website gets updated time to time so there will be some change in the data. Please refer the sheet link above

Comment: When you fetch data from a website, do you add a row or rows to CFTC or  whatever the second sheet was called?  We need to be able to look at the recovered data and check it against a saved copy in order to determine if a change has been made.  We could count the rows or look at recorded timestamps but the point is that we are not going to get a triggered event on this sort of change because there is no user action involved.

Comment: Rows will be automatically added because data was added on website only. Yes, no user action involved and that is the reason why is project is pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from cooper's idea:

Use the property service to store the value of the length of data in col A (for example). Create a time-based trigger to check the sheet every X minutes. If the data changes then update the property with the new value and send the email.

Depending on your data you can choose whatever range to test or if you have timestamps you could change the code to test for changes in time.

```
function onEdit() {

    var getProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

    var lenProp = getProps.getProperty('Len');

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('-------');

    var data = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().toString().length;

    if (data != lenProp) {
        getProps.setProperty('Len', data);
        MailApp.sendEmail('-------------', 'Sheet Has Changed', 'Previous value: ' + lenProp + ' New value: ' + data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @James this code worked for once only, not again, I don't know what happened

Comment: What type of data in the column that you are testing? If it is times and or dates the about code won't work. Can you share a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: I have attached a dummy sheet above, there are rows and columns with imported data. Th data is alphanumeric, no timestamp at all.